# How to configure webpack to generate SuiteScript compatibile modules?

Tags: webpack, amd, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to use webpack to bundle a few libraries into my typescript `suitelet`.

Netsuite expects suitescripts to follow `amd` modules pattern. If I use `tsc` tocompile my suitelet, I get correct syntax that looks this fragment:

```
/**
 *
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["require", "exports", "N", "N/file"], function (require, exports, N_1, file_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.onRequest = void 0;
    var onRequest = function (context) {
        //my actual code here
    };
    exports.onRequest = onRequest;
});
```

The poblem is that the dependencies from node_modules are not bundled. So I have tried to use webpack for this, and webpack output differs:

```
/**
 *
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["N", "N/file"], (__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE__N, __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE__Nfile) => {
    return (() => {
        //... some webpack internals goes here
        var __webpack_exports__ = {};
        // This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it need to be isolated against other modules in the chunk.
        (() => {
            __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
            /* harmony export */
            __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
                /* harmony export */   "onRequest": () => (/* binding */ onRequest)
                // harmony imports goes here, cut for readability
            });

            var onRequest = function onRequest(context) {
                //my actual code here
            };
        })();
        return __webpack_exports__;
    })();
});
```

Netsuite does not accept the version webpack produces. I **assume** that the problem is that webpack `return`s the exported module, but Netsuite expect's it to be passed as the 2nd parameter to the module factory function and modified by it. `tsc` does that. It modifies the `export` parameter adding the `onRequest` function to the `export` object. Webpack just return new object.

**How should I configure webpack to follow the `define(["require","exports","other-dependencies"], factory_function);` convention?**

Here are the fragments of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync('.src/**.ts').reduce((obj, el) => {
        obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
        return obj;
    }, {}),
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        // Do not remove the SuiteScript JSDoc when minifying
        minimize: false,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: /@NApiVersion/i,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        // Copy the SuiteScript JSDoc to the top of the script
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: data => {
                const filename = data.chunk.entryModule.resource;
                const contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'UTF-8');
                const comments = contents.match(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//);
                return comments.length ? comments[0] : '';
            },
            raw: true,
        }),
    ],
    externals: [/^N\//, /^N$/],
    externalsType: 'umd'
};
```